# How do i use @types/jqueryui along with angular2 (typescript)

Tags: jquery-ui, angular, typescript, types

I would like to use jqueryui in my angular application

I can import jquery like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

But how do i import '@types/jqueryui' from
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jqueryui

Since jqueryui is an interface, i am not able to import it

How i am using jquery

```
 export class JqueryUIIntegrationComponent implements AfterViewInit{
        @ViewChild('jqueryElement') el:ElementRef;
        constructor() {
        }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this);
        $(this.el.nativeElement).slideUp(4000).slideDown(5000); // jquery function
        $(this.el.nativeElement).draggable(); //Since jqueryui is not imported this will not work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Work Around:** (Not the solution through *@types/jqueryui* )

You can use *@types/jqueryui* for typing/autocomplete support.

**Root HTML:**

Import jquery and jquery UI js files

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**Component:**

In your component declare

```
declare var $:any;
```

use it in class like this

```
export class JqueryUIIntegrationComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('jqueryElement') el:ElementRef;
    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this);
        $(this.el.nativeElement).draggable(); //same old style
    }
}
```

**Note:** Any native support through *@types/jqueryui* (right way) is welcomed. please let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: getting error on draggable() function. Any update on this!?

Comment: .draggable() is not a function. Do you have any plunker for this?

Comment: I am working in a live project, sorry didn't create a pluker.
can you create a plunker with your usecase. so i can try to fix it?

Looking at the error message looks like you did not import Jquery UI

Make sure you have done this in your index.html

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: -1 for suggesting `declare var $:any;` instead of `npm install @types/jquery`, or one of a dozen others ways to acquire the most widely used and disbursed type declaration ever. If I got -1 again for suggesting using an AMD library as a global, I would.

Comment: Answer starts with "Work Around" that means it is not the right solution.

Comment: Please feel free to share if you have a working example jquery + jqueryUI through AMD

Answer (score 0):

Add on top of your *.ts file reference to `d.ts` types file

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"/>
```

It did the trick for me.